# How can I delete a file only if it exists?

Tags: shell

I have a shell script and I want to add a line or two where it would remove a log file only if it exists. Currently my script simply does:

```
rm filename.log
```

However if the filename doesn't exist I get a message saying filename.log does not exist, cannot remove. This makes sense but I don't want to keep seeing that every time I run the script. Is there a smarter way with an IF statement I can get this done?

Comment: Well, it's entirely impossible to remove a file that doesn't exist, so it seems that the concept of "delete a file only if it exists" is redundant. So, `rm -f filename`, or `rm filename 2>> /dev/null`, or `[[ -r filename ]] && rm filename` would be some options..

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Pass the `-f` argument to `rm`, which will cause it to treat the situation where the named file does not exist as success, and will suppress any error message in that case:

```
rm -f -- filename.log
```

What you *literally* asked for would be more like:

```
[ -e filename.log ] && rm -- filename.log
```

but it's more to type and adds extra failure modes. (If something else deleted the file after `[` tests for it but before `rm` deletes it, then you're back at having a failure again).

As an aside, the `--`s cause the filename to be treated as literal even if it starts with a leading dash; you should use these habitually if your names are coming from variables or otherwise not strictly controlled.

Comment: The solution suggested maybe does not exactly fulfil the requirements of the question. The difference is in write protected files: If the file exists and is write protected, you would get an error message with your originial solution, while the file would be silently removed by Charles Duffys solution.

Comment: @user1934428, I don't see a requirement in the question that this change in behavior countermands. Could you spell out where it's given?

Comment: Implicitly, because the OP tried to just use rm, which, if the file is present and write protected, would refuse to delete it, while the -f flag would delete it. The OP might be tempted to think that -f just removes the error message, and is perhaps not aware that he is losing safety. Admittedly, the way the question is formulated, is a bit confusing....

Comment: @user1934428, depending on `rm`'s `write_protected_non_symlink` behavior is foolish, full-stop; any "write protected" status that doesn't prevent an `unlink()` call from succeeding is purely-illusory theater.

Answer (score 9):

Touch the file first, which will create it if it's not present, but only change the timestamp if it *is* present.

```
touch filename && rm filename
```

Less efficient, but easy to remember.

Comment: very clean and simple solution I would have never thought of

Answer (score 5):

```
if [ ! -f 'absolute path of file' ]
then
  echo "File does not exist. Skipping..."
else
  rm 'absolute path of file'
fi
```

If you use the following then it should work.

Comment: Since the OP is trying to conditionalize an `rm`, vs an `echo`, the logic seems inverted here. And there's no need for the path to be absolute.

Comment: Thanks Charles!. I update it to add the file deletion login. The if expression is to test if file does not exist then skip and print a statement just for tracking if any files are missed.

Comment: Rajesh, I did try using proposal, however, I get the following error:  [ : missing ' ] ' I will try your approach as well Charles!

Comment: For if condition, make sure you put space between file path and ']'.

Comment: @user7649922, this answer *should* work -- you might see if http://shellcheck.net/ can identify the problem with the way you're trying to use it.

Comment: The spaces got me! Thanks Rajesh, this also worked however the rm -f was the simplest way out of it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

To delete a directory

```
rm -rf my/dir || true
```

To delete a file

```
rm my/file || true
```

`|| true` works if the file/directory does not exist and does not throw an error

Comment: `-r` is only relevant for _directories_, and the OP is asking about _files_. And `|| true` seems completely unrelated to the question -- you're ignoring errors for purposes of the compound command's exit status, but _not_ errors caused by the file not existing (because `-f` suppresses those already); instead, the errors you ignore are ones where the file _really does_ exist but can't be successfully deleted.

Comment: If you do this on the wrong place or make a typo, you regret ever coming to SO. No such a great advise.